# RSS feed in google chrome extension using Feed Informer

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, rss

I wanted to make my own custom new tab page in chrome and found out that I could by making my own extension. I am having problems incorporating an RSS feed into this page. I chose to use feed informer for simplicity. When I try to allow script source on the RSS feed URL I want to use I still get an error of:

> Refused to load the script 'http://feed.informer.com/widgets/KCM5VHRO76.js because
>   it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

Below is my manifest.json:

```
{
 "name": "NewTab",
 "description": "Custom Chrome new tab page",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "icons": {
 "128": "newTabIcon.png"
 },
 "chrome_url_overrides" : { 
 "newtab": "customNewTab.html"
 }
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://feed.informer.com/widgets/KCM5VHRO76.js"
}
```

and my newTab.html:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="globalStyle.css">
<header>
    <title>Newt Ab</title>
    <h1 style="background-color:green;text-align:center" > Welcome Back Luke </h1>
</header>
<body background="https://49.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lq5hs9voSZ1qm2lx2o1_400.gif">
    <h1 style="background-color:green;text-align:center">Links:</h1>
        <p style="background-color:clear;color:green;text-size:300%">
            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-lollipop/128/Gmail-icon.png"></a>
            <a href="https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=cardmail.louisville.edu#path=/mail"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dakirby309/simply-styled/128/Microsoft-Outlook-2013-icon.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-7/500/Movie_play_video_you_tube_youtube-128.png"></a>
            <a href="https://thepiratebay.se/"><img src="http://florianpellet.com/alfred/images/pirate.png"></a>
            <!--
            <a href=""><img src=""></a>
            <a href=""><img src=""></a>
            <a href=""><img src=""></a>
            -->
        </p>
    <h1 style="background-color:green;text-align:center">Feeds:</h1>
    <h1>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://feed.informer.com/widgets/KCM5VHRO76.js"></script>
            <noscript><a href="http://feed.informer.com/widgets/KCM5VHRO76.html">"Hacker News"</a>
            Powered by <a href="http://feed.informer.com/">RSS Feed Informer</a></noscript>
    </h1>
```

Is there a solution to my problem or am I approaching this wrong? By the way, I am not worried about security because I do not intend to publish this extension, it is for personal use only.

Comment: Where did you found `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://feed.informer.com/widgets/KCM5VHRO76.js"`? Are you sure that it's the right way to do this?

Comment: @MoshFeu Im not sure if is. That's the closest I've gotten in my research to make it work.